# Basic PHP program not running in in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, http, https, xampp

When I try to running following PHP script in my web browser :

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Its showing me following error, which I cannot understand as I am beginner and this error makes no sense.

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/test.php on line 1

P.S. I am using XAMPP on MAC OS X machine. And, executing script via this URL http://localhost/xampp/test.php

Comment: What happens if you try `127.0.0.1/xampp/test.php`?

Comment: Is test.php the three-line script?

Comment: set the error reporting of your source by placing this line on top of your page error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

Comment: @Darren its showing error on it.

Comment: @gonbe Yes, it the same

Answer (score 1):

you can put your file on

/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/test.php

and run it

http://localhost/test.php

Comment: Can you please tell me why my PHP programs was not running in first place ?

Comment: Yes It did. Thank you so much. You saved my day.